# Reuse project properties for a new project

Tags: visual-studio

Lately I've been working on a C++ project in Visual Studio. I had  to configure the project in every detail: libraries, linker options, optimization, optional compiler setting etc...
Now I'm moving to another similar project and I'd like to reuse the settings of the current one without manually setting them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with a project property sheet.  I typed up [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084274/adding-vc-like-project-extension-to-msvs/3084984#3084984) recently to show how to use them.

Comment: I can't export current properties to a property sheet, can I?

Comment: Well, you sorta can, it is just an XML file that you can hack with Notepad.  I wouldn't recommend it though if you don't have experience editing project and property sheet files directly.  The IDE will help you avoid making mistakes.